# Best freeware defect tracking software for Windows?

Tags: bug-tracking, defects

I'm looking for a freeware defect tracking solution. I have experience with Mercury Quality Center, but I hear that comes with a five-digit pricetag. I need something for my personal projects. Webforms (i.e. ASP.NET) would be preferrable. Anything good out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its to be used solely by you, you can get a [Fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) account for free. But it only allows up to 2 users while still being free.

I'm currently using it with a friend for my senior project

Comment: Indeed, this is be cool for personal use. FYI, Jira provides something similar called personal licenses too (but no hosting).

Answer (score 6):

I don't like BugZilla, it's very powerful but has an horrible user interface. I'd recommend [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) or [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). Nothing in ASP.NET in my basket.

Answer (score 2):

I am with the [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/) supporters.  We adopted it on our team to migrate off of a very old version of [TeamTrack](http://www.serena.com/products/teamtrack/), and we have been very impressed.  However, we were very close to using [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) instead.

And [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/), boy if we were only given the money to buy it, we would have used that in a heartbeat.  Out of all the issue trackers I reviewed, none came CLOSE to the fluidity and flexibility of JIRA while still supporting the basic functionality really well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/). It is open source and a lot of projects use it.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/).  It's not quite as powerful as Bugzilla, but you can easily get it running and configured how you like it fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Jira also has a [personal licence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/personal.jsp) available.  It is not asp.net based, but it installs easily enough, and since you aren't going to be developing on it, the technology it is build with should not matter much.

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is an option that is free regardless of the number of users.  If you use subversion, Trac has nice integration with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to [Eventum by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/other/eventum/). Free, lightweight, highly configurable and I've used it in almost all my projects.